# Lower SFTP overhead on the client side?

Tags: performance, ftp, protocols

I'm using Putty SFTP 0.63 to connect to a server on a nightly basis to download 37,000 tiny files (less than a kb each), using mget.

It takes 4 hours to download the 37,000 tiny files, and I'm sure that's because of the protocol overhead of doing 1 transfer 37,000 times.  We have tested zipping the files into one "big" one (about 30MB) and of course it transfers in seconds.  The problem is that I don't have control over the IT systems that are generating those files that I need to fetch, and I've been assured that they will never zip/tar/whatever the files on the server end, at least in my lifetime.

Does anyone know of any tricks I can pull to lower the per-file overhead and maybe speed things up?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have SFTP access, are you sure you can't run an ssh command to zip the files before the transfer?

Comment: Good idea, but I just tried and "Server refused to start a shell/command", so I guess not.

Comment: You may just want to make the request to IT to zip the files.  Usually when there's a good reason to do something, especially when your beating on the server and the network for 4 hours, they might be somewhat sympathetic.  It doesn't hurt to ask...

Comment: That's plan B if I can't rewire the internet.  I'll show them some benchmarks and say c'mon!